# How to sort array of objects keys based on another array keys position

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with correct order line:

```
let arr1 = ['name', 'age', 'occupation', 'address']
```

and I have an another array which is coming from the backend with unsorted format

```
let arr2 = [{'age': 20, 'address': '', 'occupation': 'student', 'name': 'student name1'}, {'age': 21, 'address': '', 'occupation': 'student', 'name': 'student name2'}, {'age': 22, 'address': '', 'occupation': 'student', 'name': 'student name3'}]
```

So I need this **arr2** objects keys to be sorted the way **arr1** keys index positions.

Final output needed:

```
let arr2Sorted = [{ 'name': 'student name1', 'age': 20, 'occupation': 'student', 'address': ''}, { 'name': 'student name2', 'age': 21, 'occupation': 'student', 'address': ''}, { 'name': 'student name3', 'age': 22, 'occupation': 'student', 'address': ''}]
```

What I tried:

```
const arrayMap = arr2.reduce(
      (accumulator, currentValue) => ({
         ...accumulator,
         [currentValue]: currentValue,
      }),
     {},
    );

const result = arr1.map((key) => arrayMap[key]);
```

Comment: It is not so easy to enforce the order of the keys in a JavaScript object. Moreover order is generally not important when dealing with key -> values. Why do you need this?

Comment: the arr1 is client side array that I use this to render table headers, so the key name is the first table column, followed by other keys in the arr1 order, but arr2 that's coming from backend with that order to make it re-usable and dynamic  rendering, I need to sort it,  to reuse this same table in multiple modules

Comment: `let arr1 = ['name', 'age', 'occupation', 'address']` is not really "sorted" but more on the line of "ordered" since I fail to see any "sort" that would produce that order

Comment: Your question reads like "How can I do X by using Z" rather than "How can I best do X"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let arr1 = ['name', 'age', 'occupation', 'address'];
let arr2 = [{'age': 20, 'address': '', 'occupation': 'student', 'name': 'student name1'}, {'age': 21, 'address': '', 'occupation': 'student', 'name': 'student name2'}, {'age': 22, 'address': '', 'occupation': 'student', 'name': 'student name3'}];

let arr3 = arr2.map(i=>Object.fromEntries(arr1.map(p=>[p,i[p]])));

console.log(arr3);
```

Comment: Thanks, I never though of using Object.fromEntries for this, it's good

Comment: Pretty good compact code answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Here I show why it is probably not needed to order the properties, but just use them.  I also answer the "How To" in a verbose way.

```js
let arr1 = ['name', 'age', 'occupation', 'address'];
let arr2 = [{
  'age': 20,
  'address': '',
  'occupation': 'student',
  'name': 'student name1'
}, {
  'age': 21,
  'address': '',
  'occupation': 'student',
  'name': 'student name2'
}, {
  'age': 22,
  'address': '',
  'occupation': 'student',
  'name': 'student name3'
}];
// show it is not needed to order props, just use them
const container = document.getElementById("container");
arr2.forEach((el) => {
  arr1.forEach((nm) => {
    const newtext = document.createTextNode(nm + ":" + el[nm]);
    let dv = document.createElement('div');
    dv.appendChild(newtext);
    container.appendChild(dv);
  });
});

// now show how we an order the props - a number of ways to do this
// this is a super verbose way for clarity
let arrPropsOrdered = [];
arr2.forEach((el, index, array) => {
  // console.log("PropName:",arr1[0]);
  // console.log("Object:",el);
  // console.log("ObjectNameProp:",el[arr1[0]]);
  let x = {};
  /* manual way
  x[arr1[0]] = el[arr1[0]];
  x[arr1[1]] = el[arr1[1]];
  x[arr1[2]] = el[arr1[2]];
  x[arr1[3]] = el[arr1[3]];
  */
  // in a loop
  arr1.forEach((nm) => {
    x[nm] = el[nm];
  });
 // console.log("X:", x);
  arrPropsOrdered.push(x);
  // show it pushed in there using the current index
 // console.log("PropsByPropName:", arrPropsOrdered[index]);
});

// console.log(arrPropsOrdered);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```